# how to get the type of the inner class' parent

Tags: c++

```
struct Parent
{
 struct Inner
 {
 }
};

void foo()
{
 bar<Parent::Inner>();
} 

template<class T>
void bar()
{
 //here I would like to get the type of T class' parent
}
```

In the above code, is it possible without writing a protocol or put a typedef inside Inner class to get the type of the parent's inner class ?

Comment: You mean _the type of the inner class' parent_.

Comment: @jasal:yes I have updated

Comment: That's not possible without a typedef.

Answer (score 2):

Without using `typedef` or `using` then it's not possible to access to the container's type. However you can specialize the `bar` function where you know what the container's type is.

```
template<> void bar<Parent::Inner>()
{
  // Here, you know what the parent is
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple `using`:

```
struct Parent
{
  struct Inner
  {
    using parent_type = Parent;
  };

};

template<class T>
void bar()
{
  //here I would like to get T's parent type
  typename T::parent_type t;
}
```

Also note that `bar<Inner>();` is ill-formed. You need

```
bar<Parent::Inner>();
```

Comment: Indeed it's the logical and usual way. However the OP wants not to use `typedef` nor `using`.

Comment: @MM. OP doesn't say anything about `using` :-)

Comment: Smart, however we both know that `typedef` and `using` are somehow the same and what the OP means ;-)